# given sequence diverges finding epsilon values

Tags: real-analysis

The sequence $s_n = (−1)^n$ does not converge.

1. For what values of $\epsilon > 0$ is it nonetheless true that there is an
   integer $N$ so that $|s_n − 1| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$?
2. For what values of$\epsilon > 0$ is it nonetheless true that there is
   an integer $N$ so that $|s_n − 0| < ε$ whenever $n \ge N$?

For part 1. I have set up the distance equivalence:
$$1-\epsilon < (-1)^n <1+\epsilon$$
then i solved for $n$ by taking the log of both sides. Is this correct? 
I know B will follow the same suit, but i know we didn't do anything with logs.. can you give me some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be screwing with you a little, but OK.

The quantity $|s_n-1|$ oscillates between 0 and 2, since $s_n$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$. Because of this we can say that $\forall \varepsilon > 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|s_n -1| \leqslant 2 < \varepsilon$.

Similarly, $|s_n - 0|$ is a fixed value - it's 1. For any $\varepsilon > 1$, the same logic as above holds.

I think the point being made here is the difference between existential and universal quantifiers. The definition of convergence only holds for some values of $\varepsilon$, and not all values, hence the sequence cannot converge.

Comment: thank you, yes i was over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-thinking it. Remember that $n$ is an integer. What values does $(-1)^n$ take on for integers $n$?